# Send notification at a certain time

Tags: java, android

I have this code that send a notification. I copied from one of the forums here ! So this code says that sends a notification in a certain time , but i'm not being able to send it , any problems with my code ?

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Testes.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Testes.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Testes.this.getSystemService(Testes.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmReceiver.class:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static int MID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Testes.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.grades_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Alarm Fired")
                .setContentText("Events To be PErformed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;

    }

}
```

Comment: take a look at onesignal. they make things like this so damn easy.

Comment: sure will do thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Alarm Code that works just fine.

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "");
    wl.acquire();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
    sendNotification("Alarm",context);
    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(context, AlarmActivity.class); //AlarmActivity is a dummy class name where to redirect
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("msg","Task Pending");
    context.startActivity(intent);
    wl.release();
}
```

`sendNotification(String s,Context c)` is given below.

```
private void sendNotification(String body,Context context) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WelcomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //Set sound of notification
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("lalalalalala lalalalalal lalalalalalal lalalalaaa")
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification not = notifiBuilder
                .setContentTitle("The Big Notification")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(notifiBuilder)
                        .bigLargeIcon(icon))
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(123456 /*ID of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
    }
```

and then in my AlarmActivity the code is as follow.

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Ringtone r;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, notification);
    r.play();

    ImageView buttonCancelAlarm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancelAlarm);

    buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancelAlarm(Test.this);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    r.stop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

and you can add your alarm through this `function`

```
 public void setAlarm(Context context, long millisec)
    {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
            AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I hope it helps. Now you can add your calendar intent in it and it will work.